# Show all values in a matrix except for a value at the intersection of the 2nd row and 3rd column

Tags: r, matrix

```
x <- matrix(1:25, nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
```

From matrix “x” show all elements except the value at the intersection of the second row and third column.

Comment: You can only mask certain columns or rows. Perhaps, you can set the unwanted element to NA: `x[2,3] <- NA` and print `x`

Comment: @slava-kohut thank you, I will try this method.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might be useful:

```
masked.display <- function(A,i,j) {
  A[i,j] <- ''
  noquote(A)
}
```

For example,

```
> A <- matrix(1:12,nrow = 3)
> masked.display(A,2,3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] 1    4    7    10  
[2,] 2    5         11  
[3,] 3    6    9    12
```

The advantage of abstracting it to a function is that then the assignment `A[i,j] <- ''` doesn't modify the matrix itself. In this case, `A[2,3]` is still 6 after the function runs.